# Asking which laptops have a particular keyboard design: on or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The keyboard layout of the [Lenovo S210](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HIY9KSY) is easy and intuitive for me to use. The laptop is just a little underpowered for me. I asked Lenovo support if any of their other models have a similar keyboard layout, and they couldn't find one. So I want to ask the community if anyone knows of laptops, by any manufacturer, that have a keyboard similar to the S210 in the following ways

1. the `Ctrl` key is the lower-leftmost key, and
2. `Home, End, Page Up, Page Down` commands can be executed with a combination of `Fn` and the arrow keys.

Before asking this on the main site, I wanted to check that this question wouldn't be considered "[asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)". Would this question be on- of off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

Its a hardware recommendation - Its clearly, and explicitly off topic.

> Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic
>   because they are often relevant only to the question author at the
>   time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly.
>   Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits
>   your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it would be off-topic for exactly the reason you stated. This is basically a request for links to models of other laptops with the same keyboard. *That's not knowledge*. That's shopping.